# Java: How can I store a value in a variable with continues timestamp without getting into a database?

Tags: java, variables, time, timestamp

How I can store a value in an array variable say `x`.
At every instance, whenever we have a value for `x` or when we don't have a value for `x`, we can have a time. Like at instance 1 millisec, `x` has value 245 and at 3 millisec, x has value 300.
How do I do this in Java without using or storing values in a Database?

Comment: You'll need to be clearer.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard I am storing frequencies from the microphone input .If I have to map one's performance I have to store then with respect to time . Is it possible to store values of frequencies in  an array and mark the time of each value contentiously using a timer or a counter

Comment: An `int[]`?! i.e. `values[1] = 245`

Comment: @Arunroy Perhaps describe what you are trying to do, what you've tried, and mabye post some code. It's preatty hard to make sense out of the question right now.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard   That is simple intialization, What I mean is at millisec 0 int x[0] =243 similarly at milllisec 2 x[4] =342 . How do I record time while storing a value in variable ?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know what you are doing based on the description, but if your intention is to store a piece of intelligence (some integer value, say) with a corresponding monotonically increasing value such as a timestamp in millis, you should use a data structure or object to do so. I often refer to such a fundamenal data piece as an "atom".

If you will never need a more complicated atom than a long - int relationship, you could use some sort of Map.

If you ever intend to make this atom more complicated, you might want to create your own object. The nice thing about this way is that you can build in error handling (e.g., time not increasing monotonically, or apparent gaps). It also makes it a little more straightforward when persisting/caching this data to some store so you can work on datasets larger than memory. This last part is probably the trickiest part of your design.

Answer (score 1):

@Arunroy in base on my understanding of posible question i have a example i wrote. It possibly could help you, it has a class that implements an interface Serializable that enable the class to be serializable in other words to be stored in a file and then be read. This process is called serialization. The class creates a file and store the class inside the file. Then with the deserialization process you can read it.

The code:

```
package storage;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class MyValues{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();

        MyData d = new MyData(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        System.out.println(""+d.tiempo);
        serialize(d);
        deSerialize();

    }

    public static boolean serialize(MyData a) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut
                    = new FileOutputStream("c:\\myfolder1\\mydata.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(a);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in c:\\myfolder1\\mydata.ser \n");
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void deSerialize() {
        MyData a = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("c:\\myfolder1\\employee.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            a = (MyData) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            System.out.println("Employee class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Deserialized MyData...");
        System.out.println("TimeStamp: " + a.tiempo);
        return;
    }


}

class MyData implements Serializable{
    public Timestamp tiempo;

    public MyData(Timestamp tiempo) {
        this.tiempo = tiempo;
    }

}
```